# If my column contains a number from 1 to 25 return a concatenation of that number + my column

Tags: excel

I am trying to ask Excel to look in say cell A1 if it finds within my text in cell A1 a number from 1 to 25, if yes to return a concatenation of the number it finds + _ + what is in cell A1

Example:

A1 contains: `Assignment 18`
I want excel to give me `18_Assignment 18` in cell B1

A2 contains: `Assignment 1`
I want excel to give me `01_Assignment 1` in cell B2

So far, this is my coding. I know this is incomplete.  Could you please help with this challenge?

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$1:$D$25, A1)), $D$1:$D$25+_+A1,A1)
```

Please note that D1:25 contains numbers from 1 to 25

```
D1 contains: 1
D2 contains: 2
...
D25 contains: 25
```

Then I want to be able to drag my code and apply it to all the cells in column A

Thank you so much!

Best,
Aliza

Comment: Do all the cells in question follow this pattern `Assignment [number]`? If so, it's easy: `=TEXT(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),"00")&"_"&A1`

Comment: Well, if it's exactly this pattern I'd say: `=TEXT(--RIGHT(A1,2),"00")&"_"&A1`

Answer (score 1):

For all versions of Excel since 2010:

```
=IFERROR(TEXT(INDEX($D$1:$D$25,AGGREGATE(15,7,$D$1:$D$25/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$D$1:$D$25&" "," "&A1&" "))),1)),"00")&"_","")&A1
```

All `$D$1:$D$25` can be replaced with `ROW(1:25)` if desired.  It would negate the need of having the numbers stored in a range.

[image]

With Office 365:

```
=LET(rng,A1,
    nm,SEQUENCE(25),
    flt,FILTER(nm,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&nm&" "," "&rng&" ")),""),
    IF(flt="","",flt&"_")&rng)
```

Comment: `IF(flt="","",TEXT(flt,"00")&"_")&rng` for Office 365 solution, and `ROW($1:$25)` instead of `ROW(1:25)`.

Comment: Toying around a bit with this still, `=IFERROR(TEXT(INDEX(ROW($1:$25),AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW($1:$25)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(ROW($1:$25),A1))=TRUE), 1)),"00")&"_","")&A1` would also work on a string like `Assignment18` or `_18` etc.